# Верстка под IE

Tags: internet-explorer, вёрстка

Здравствуйте ХешКод, я начал заниматься web-программированием, и решил сделать свой первый сайт (http://chat-profit.org.ua/test/). Посмотрите через Goodle Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, Safari всё работает отлично, открываю через IE 8,9 господи... Где прозрачность у блоков, почему список сообщений слез вниз? Но есть такая фишка - вчера скачал якобы IE 10.00 и там менюшки Debug With **

**Версия IE

Посмотрел под 5, нету прозрачности, 7, тоже нету, 8 уже что-то намечается, в 9-м уже всё очень неплохо смотрится, но я не совсем понял. У меня Windows 7 и там по умолчанию уже есть IE 9, и почему-то когда я запускаю через IE 9 то сайт кривой, а если с IE 10.00, но подключаю отображение через IE 9, то всё нормально.

Я пробовал искать материал в Гугле, но там предлагают такие безумные методы "исправления" сайта, что лучше даже не смотреть. Так вот скажите, может быть раз у меня такая проблема с IE, может просто вылавливать пользователей, которые сидят с IE и не давать им доступ?

Comment: 39% принятых ......исправте ситуацию.

Answer (score 3):

1.В Ie много багов в поведении блоков. Прозрачности `opacity` нету поддержки (вместо нее [фильтр Alpha](http://www.xiper.net/manuals/css-extensions/internet-explorer/filters/alpha.html)).

2.Под IE5 никто не верстает (там очень сложная верстка, количество пользователей малое).
Сейчас верстают не ниже IE7.

3.

> Я пробовал искать материал в Гугле, но там предлагают такие безумные методы "исправления" сайта, что лучше даже не смотреть

Вот это и есть верстка под IE.

4.Запретить доступ к вашему сайту людям с IE, конечно, можно, но зачем? Хочет - пусть сидит.
Можно вывести сообщение только для их с просьбой сменить браузер.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> <div class="ie6">
Браузер, который вы используете, не может корректно отобразить эту страницу. Пожалуйста, обновите его.
</div> <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Учитесь еще. Это нельзя назвать хорошей версткой, теги старые используете, линих ксс свойств много. Учитесь по книгам новым, читайте оф документацию.

По поводу прозрачности, то в ие по дефолту у фреймов бгшка белая, потому они не прозрачные, убирите бг через ксс.

Comment: Учиться ему явно есть чему...

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри видео про заглушку ие: [Как установить заглушку для IE6](http://info-line.net/css/videokurs-css/14-videourok-kursa-po-css-kak-ustanovit-zaglushku-dlya-ie6.html).